# Is it possible to filter certain text only cells?

Tags: python, regex

I have around 10 000 data like this:

| Row | Effect |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3_prime_UTR_variant,intron_variant |
| 2 | missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,missense_variant,non_coding_transcript_exon_variant,non_coding_transcript_exon_variant,non_coding_transcript_exon_variant,non_coding_transcript_exon_variant,non_coding_transcript_exon_variant,non_coding_transcript_exon_variant,non_coding_transcript_exon_variant,non_coding_transcript_exon_variant,non_coding_transcript_exon_variant,non_coding_transcript_exon_variant,non_coding_transcript_exon_variant |
| 3 | intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant,intron_variant |

I wanted to filtered out with regex patter only cells cotained intron_variant. I tried this pattern in python:

```
pattern = r'^(intron_variant)|(,intron_variant)|(,intron_variant)$'
```

But it still picked all cells containing text intron_variant. Is it even possible to pick intron_variant only cells?

__

Regex \b option unfortunatelly did not work. I still get effect of 1. sample as result, eventhough i need only 3. row effect to filter out.

Comment: I am new here so I am opened to necessary edits related to this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using pandas (which I assume you do), you can use the following:

```
df[df["Effect"] == 'bintron_variant']
```

This filters out the dataframe in a similar fashion to SQL (where Effect = 'bintron_variant'). It returns a dataframe, so you can save this as a new dataframe as well.